# entry points from setup.py not recognized

Tags: python, flask, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to get an entry point to run my flask application.

I think its due to the directory structure:

```
my_app
  - __init__.py
  - app.py  
  - setup.py
  - etc..
```

My setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os.path

def read_requirements(pathname):
    with open(pathname) as f:
        return [line for line in (x.strip() for x in f) if not line.startswith('#')]

def project_path(*names):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *names)

setup(
    name='my_app',
    version='0.1.0',

    install_requires=read_requirements(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt')),

    test_suite='nose.collector',

    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'START_ME=app:run',
        ],
    },
    classifiers=["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7"],
    description=__doc__,
    long_description='\n\n'.join(open(project_path(name)).read() for name in (
            'README.md',
            )),
    zip_safe=False,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=find_packages(),
    )
```

I think the `find_packages()` method is not picking up the fact that its in the package, maybe its looking in lower level directories for packages? I've tried `find_packages('.')` to try get it to search in the project root directory but this did not work.

Can I get this to work without changing my directory structure?

[Here](https://github.com/ThriceGood/Mimic) is the actual project.

Also, I noticed that when I run setup.py install I get a top_level.txt file in my egg.info folder, it says that the top level is actually a package that exists inside of the root/main package, like:

```
 / main_package
     - __init__.py
     - app.py
     / sub_package
         - __init__.py
         - sub.py
```

in the top_level.txt file, `sub_package` is written.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up putting all the flask app files into a sub directory inside the project root directory. fixed it nicely.

```
/project
  - setup.py
  /flask_app
    - __init__.py
    - app.py
```